# Cascade delete in a one-to-one relationship in Access

Tags: ms-access, delete-row, one-to-one, cascade

New to Access so please excuse me for the basic question ...

I have two tables in an Access database (Office 365 enterprise) for which I have setup a one to one relationship using the relationships tab (I have setup the same unique field in each table and used as pk/fk). I have checked "Enforce Referential Integrity", "Cascade Update Related Fields" and "Cascade Delete Related Records". In Access, I right-click the child table and click "open", I then right-click a record and select "delete". However, when I check for the matching record in the parent table it is still there.

What am I missing here? Does the delete need to be done in SQL for the cascade delete to work?

Comment: Cascade suggests parent->child flow. You are wanting child->parent flow. Perhaps your relationship is set up backwards?

Comment: Perhaps I was looking at the problem from the wrong angle. I imagine child-parent flow is uncommon in the database world? Will chat with the team to see if this is needed, thinking the parent-child framework will work. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: The part that is not common is that a child table in most cases can have "many" reocrds. But in your case, only one. But from a relatonal view, we always start with the parent table and work our way down - not up.  So, for the most part, deleting the child record(s) will not flow up to the parent table. If you want to delete that row, then your code will and should have to execute the delete code against the parent table row - not  the child one. Quite such that most databases work this way - including access.

Comment: Thanks @AlbertD.Kallal for your comment. This helps put things in perspective.